# return self struct clone in golang (without reflect)

Tags: go

there are two structs,
`Foo` has a `Clone()` method
`Bar` is inherit from `Foo`

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IF interface {
    Clone() IF
}

type Foo struct {
    i int
}

func (this *Foo) Clone() IF {
    c := *this
    return &c
}

type Bar struct {
    Foo
}

func main() {
    t := &Bar{}
    c := t.Clone()
    fmt.Printf(`%T `, t)
    fmt.Printf(`%T `, c)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pFn348aydW

output is

```
*main.Bar *main.Foo
```

but I want clone a `Bar`, not `Foo`
I must add `Bar.Clone()` exactly the same as `Foo.Clone()`

```
func (this *Bar) Clone() IF {
    c := *this
    return &c
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/J6jT_0f1WW

Now the output is what I want

```
*main.Bar *main.Bar
```

If I will write lots of struct like `Bar`, I won't write lots of `Clone()`, what I can do ?
It is best not to use reflect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go doesn't have inheritance, this is composition, not inheritance, which is why you're getting frustrated. Bar doesn't inherit from Foo, it embeds Foo, which is very different. When embedding, the embedded methods act on the embedded struct, not the wrapper, so yes you're correct, you must add a bar Clone() if you want something returning a Bar.

Probably it's better to step back and consider why you're embedding Foo though - don't try to use Foo like a base class, think of it more as a module of code you're importing (self-contained, refers only to data in Foo, not in Bar). So obviously this is just a toy example, but to extend it to illustrate what Foo does:

```
type Foo struct {
    i int
}

func (f *Foo) String() string {
    if f.i > 0 {
        return fmt.Sprintf("val:%d", f.i)
    }
    return ""
}

type Bar struct {
    Foo
}

// Bar conforms to Stringer by virtue of embedding Foo
// using the Foo data stored in i 
type Stringer interface {
    String() string
}

func Print(b Stringer) {
    fmt.Printf("%s", b)
}

func main() {
    b := &Bar{}
    Print(b) // Outputs empty string
    b.i = 4
    Print(b) // Outputs val:4
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/tNWPVw79aa

So you can use Foo methods but they should only relate to contents of the Foo struct, and you should probably just keep everything in Bar till you're very sure you need Foo for some reason, then break it out - Go will guide you towards minimal complexity, and does not support inheritance for that reason.

In languages supporting inheritance you might start your design process by producing a lovely big taxonomy of classes with abstract base classes factories etc. In go you start by considering the data and behaviour attached to it or acting on it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Composition vs inheritance

Go does not provide inheritance instead of it Go provides composition.

**Composition**:

> In computer science, object composition is a way to combine simple objects or data types into more complex ones.

**Inheritance**:

> In object-oriented programming, inheritance is when an object or class is based on another object or class, using the same implementation or specifying a new implementation to maintain the same behavior.

#### Go composition implementation

It is possible to combine several structs into single composition but each method hasn't access to outer struct or other composed structs. Also outer struct has access to inner structs. You should treat outer (not parent) struct as wrapper for inner (not child) structs.

[Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) says:

> There's an important way in which embedding differs from subclassing. When we embed a type, the methods of that type become methods of the outer type, but when they are invoked the receiver of the method is the inner type, not the outer one.

Since what you tried to do is impossible, please see mostly the same [snippet](https://play.golang.org/p/X76xYKV63u) as yours, but with more clear and idiomatic design (I believe it could give you a right idea for the implementation):

```
type IF interface {
    DoSomething()
}

type Foo struct {
    i int
}

func (f *Foo) DoSomething() {}

type Cloner struct {
    *Foo
}

func (this *Cloner) Clone() IF {
    c := *this.Foo
    return &c
}

func main() {
    f := new(Foo)
    t := &Cloner{f}
    c := t.Clone()
    fmt.Printf("%T \n", t)
    fmt.Printf("%p \n", f)
    fmt.Printf("%p ", c)
}
```

Comment: He's not returning a pointer to the same object, he's copying it with the `c := *this` line.  That creates a new variable and sets it equal to a _copy_ of the object that `this` points to (ie. the actual object, not the pointer).  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/YFQjbrZ3-7